# jQuery after return to previous page

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem: when I scroll to the end of page, then go on to some product and then return back by clicking return button at browser, I don't go back at the last of page but about at the middle of the page, and after that images above have *opacity: 0* until I begin scrolling. I am using jQuery code for such fade effect for images while scrolling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

 tiles = $('.ajax_block_product, .pagination, .pagination label, #nb_item,     .button_mini, .button').fadeTo(0,0);

 $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 210;
        if (a < b) { $(this).fadeTo(2500,1); }
    });
 });

 function inWindow(s){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var currentEls = $(s);
  var result = [];
  currentEls.each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var offset = el.offset();
      if (scrollTop <= offset.top && (el.height() + offset.top) < (scrollTop + windowHeight + 210)) {
          result.push(this); }
  });
  return $(result);
}

inWindow('.ajax_block_product, .pagination, .pagination label, #nb_item, .button_mini,     .button').fadeTo(0,1);

});
</script>
```

And here is the link - http://layot.prestatrend.com/
So, could anybody help me please how to avoid this back return issue?